# Dropzone error on crossdomain file upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dropzone.js

I want to upload file from on server to other server with **dropzone**. But I keep geting error `Server responded with 0 code`. Dropzone only send Option request to target server. Request And response headers are here. After that i get the `error('0 code');`
I Also set Headers to my php script. Which are these.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$pathToOrigin);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:false');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age:1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, cache-control, content-type, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-headers');
```

[requuest headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdYeu.png)

Comment: show the js setup you have? for `dropzone`

Comment: $("div#drop").dropzone(
        {
            url: "<?php echo $pathToUploadFiles ?>",
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            addRemoveLinks:true,
            sending: function(file, xhr, formData)
            {
                formData.append('k1', $('#k1').val());
                console.log('sending');
            },
            success: function(file) {
                this.removeFile(file);
            },
            queuecomplete: function(){
                toastr.info("Files are Uploaded Successfully!");
            }

        });

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, I updated your sending function to:

```
  method: 'put',
  this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
    formData.append('k1', $('#k1').val());
    var _send = xhr.send;
    xhr.send = function() {
      _send.call(xhr, file);
    }
  });
```

```js
$("div#drop").dropzone({
  method: 'put',
  url: "<?php echo $pathToUploadFiles ?>",
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
    formData.append('k1', $('#k1').val());
    var _send = xhr.send;
    xhr.send = function() {
      _send.call(xhr, file);
    }
  });
  success: function(file) {
    this.removeFile(file);
  },
  queuecomplete: function() {
    toastr.info("Files are Uploaded Successfully!");
  }
});
```

Comment: Nothing! Its still the same

Comment: @M.SUFIANAZEEM also added `method: 'put',` and updated sending function.

Comment: I tried it too.still Same response  And only send Option request.

Answer (score 0):

I tried put methode too.still Same response.  browser only send (Option) request. Here is the image of browser response.
[Image of Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1nXm.png)